# How to convert an existing A4 PDF document to an A3 booklet?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Hi We have a requirement to convert an existing A4 size pdf to A3 Size PDF in java. Since i am new to itext api conversion pdfs, Can anyone guide me how to do in java using itext or any other api to do. If sample reference provided then appreciable.

UPDATe: Output PDF should be in A3 booklet format.

Comment: you could use ghostscript and call it via a command call in Java

Comment: thanks. I need to generate pdfs in  bulk,i can't use commandline . Any Alternative is there?

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what "convert A4 to A3" means. Do you want to scale the content so the A3 page looks the same as the A4 page? Do you want to preserve the content size, adding white space around it on the A3 page? Do you want to put 2 A4 pages on 1 A3 page?

Comment: @rhens, I need to put the A4 pages on A3 page.

Comment: I need to convert to be A3 size booklet format

Comment: Have you tried using `PdfWriter`, `PdfReader` and `PdfImportedPage`? If not, why not? If the answer is: "because I want someone else to do my job", please think again.

Comment: Take a look at the [NUpTool](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#263-nuptool.java) and simplify it to *not* scale the original pages down but instead use a larger output format

Comment: Why would command-line not be applicable for a situation where you want to batch process files? Most automated workflows I work on use command-line tools extensively.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [MakeA3Booklet](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/create-a3-booklet-a4-document#1568-makea3booklet.java) example.
In this example, we take an existing PDF document with 299 A4 pages ([primes.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/primes.pdf)) and we convert it to a 150-page A3 booklet ([a3_booklet.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/merge/cmp_a3_booklet.pdf)):

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A3.rotate());
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    float a4_width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    int p = 0;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    while (p++ < n) {
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, p);
        if (p % 2 == 1) {
            canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            canvas.addTemplate(page, a4_width, 0);
            document.newPage();
        }
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

We create a `Document` object with `PageSize.A3` as parameter, but as `PageSize.A3` is in portrait, we rotate it so that we get the page size in landscape. We need the width of the A4 page (which is half of the width of the A3 page in landscape format) and we loop over all the pages in the existing document.

If we encounter an odd page, we add it at position `(x = 0; y = 0)`. If we encounter an even page, we add it at position `(x = a4_width; y = 0)` and we create a new page.