# How to convert an A4 size PDF to an A3 PDF booklet?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need a variation on the example given in answer to the following question: [How to convert an existing A4 PDF document to an A3 booklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019298/how-to-convert-an-existing-a4-pdf-document-to-an-a3-booklet)

I have more or less the same requirement, but I don't want the consecutive pages to appear side by side on the same page.

For instance: if I have the following file

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-C7-T2Eefr8dmxGZlhIbG10aWM

I want the output to be like this:

- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-C7-T2Eefr8RDBXUEg3NFQwTDg.

Please suggest me how to do using iText.

Comment: (1.) The files you "share" require permission. We can not open them. (2.) you yourself mark the question as duplicate. That's asking for this question to be closed as duplicate. (3.) Without looking at the files (I can't open them), I'd guess that you want the order of the pages to be changed. If that's the case, then what did you try? Changing the order of pages is a simple mathematical exercise.

Comment: @Bruno ..sorry to make access to web of above shared links. Please verify now.

Comment: How will your book be bound. Will pages be grouped by 16? Currently, you aren't providing sufficient info for anyone to provide you with the correct formula. However, if you check the Math you learned in high school, you'll discover that it's simply a matter of calculating which page goes where. (I wanted to mark this question as duplicate, but unfortunately nobody upvoted my answer. If people don't accept / up-vote good answers, I start doubting why I even bother answering...)

Comment: This page explains how booklets are usually made: http://dreamingincmyk.com/2014/05/19/page-counts-explained/ (I'm adding this link in case you didn't understand why I asked you if pages will be grouped by 16?)

Answer (score 1):

When a book is printed, the machines that print the pages actually print on much larger pages, and that larger page is then usually cut and folded. You'll see that most books have a total number of pages that is dividable by 16. For instance, when I wrote my "iText in Action" books, extra pages with advertisements for other books were added so that the total number of pages would be a multiple of 16.

This shows how pages are typically printed:

[image]
(The image was taken from a blog entitled "[Page counts explained](http://dreamingincmyk.com/2014/05/19/page-counts-explained/)")

We can easily convert a document with A4 pages to a document with pages 8 times the size of A4, where we add 8 pages of the original document to a single page in the new document, organized the way is shown in the above image. This is done in the [MakeBooklet](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/create-booklet-a4-document#1577-makebooklet.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // step 1
    Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(
        PageSize.A4.getWidth() * 4,
        PageSize.A4.getHeight() * 2);
    Document document = new Document(pagesize);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    float a4_width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
    float a4_height = PageSize.A4.getHeight();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    int p = 1;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    while ((p - 1) / 16 <= n / 16) {
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 3, 0);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 12, a4_width);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 15, a4_width * 2);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p, a4_width * 3);
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(-Math.PI);
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(0, -a4_height * 2));
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.concatCTM(at);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 4, -a4_width);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 11, -a4_width * 2);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 8, -a4_width * 3);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 7, -a4_width * 4);
        canvas.restoreState();
        document.newPage();
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 1, 0);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 14, a4_width);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 13, a4_width * 2);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 2, a4_width * 3);
        canvas.saveState();
        canvas.concatCTM(at);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 6, -a4_width);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 9, -a4_width * 2);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 10, -a4_width * 3);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 5, -a4_width * 4);
        canvas.restoreState();
        document.newPage();
        p += 16;
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}

public void addPage(PdfContentByte canvas,
        PdfReader reader, int p, float x) {
    if (p > reader.getNumberOfPages()) return;
    PdfImportedPage page = canvas.getPdfWriter().getImportedPage(reader, p);
    canvas.addTemplate(page, x, 0);
}
```

In the `manipulatePdf()` method, we create a loop in which we add 2 pages. On each page, we add 8 pages of the original PDF, but we add these on very specific places. For the bottom row of 4 pages, we introduce a translation (we move `a4_width` to the right for every new page). Then we introduce a rotation to add the top row of pages (they need to be upside-down).

That's fun isn't it? Actually, it's just a matter of Math (and Math is *always* fun). You can find the result here: [book16.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/merge/cmp_book16.pdf)

Your question is less fun because it's so simple. You don't even need to rotate your pages! Take a look at the [MakeBookletA3](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/create-booklet-a4-document#1578-makebookleta3.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // step 1
    Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(
        PageSize.A4.getWidth() * 2,
        PageSize.A4.getHeight());
    Document document = new Document(pagesize);
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
        = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    float a4_width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    int p = 1;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    while ((p - 1) / 4 <= n / 4) {
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 3, 0);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p, a4_width);
        document.newPage();
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 1, 0);
        addPage(canvas, reader, p + 2, a4_width);
        document.newPage();
        p += 4;
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}

public void addPage(PdfContentByte canvas,
        PdfReader reader, int p, float x) {
    if (p > reader.getNumberOfPages()) return;
    PdfImportedPage page = canvas.getPdfWriter().getImportedPage(reader, p);
    canvas.addTemplate(page, x, 0);
}
```

Now we only create 2 pages in the loop, and we add 2 old pages to every new page. The result: [book4.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/merge/cmp_book4.pdf)

Comment: thanks Bruno.. I am trying to write according to your guidence...thanks so much to make post us in details... Since i am new to this blog, i can't upvote otherwise i can upvote